# How to fix TypeError: CSS2Properties doesn't have an indexed property setter for '0'

Tags: css, reactjs, cross-browser, material-ui

I am using reactJs and material UI for application development.
when I am opening an application in Mozilla Firefox it gives me an error 
`"TypeError: CSS2Properties doesn't have an indexed property setter for '0'"` 
and my navigation are not working. Please give me any solution.

```
var CSSPropertyOperations = {

  /**
   * Serializes a mapping of style properties for use as inline styles:
   *
   *   > createMarkupForStyles({width: '200px', height: 0})
   *   "width:200px;height:0;"
   *
   * Undefined values are ignored so that declarative programming is easier.
   * The result should be HTML-escaped before insertion into the DOM.
   *
   * @param {object} styles
   * @param {ReactDOMComponent} component
   * @return {?string}
   */
  createMarkupForStyles: function (styles, component) {
    var serialized = '';
    for (var styleName in styles) {
      if (!styles.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {
        continue;
      }
      var styleValue = styles[styleName];
      if (false) {
        warnValidStyle(styleName, styleValue, component);
      }
      if (styleValue != null) {
        serialized += processStyleName(styleName) + ':';
        serialized += dangerousStyleValue(styleName, styleValue, component) + ';';
      }
    }
    return serialized || null;
  },

  /**
   * Sets the value for multiple styles on a node.  If a value is specified as
   * '' (empty string), the corresponding style property will be unset.
   *
   * @param {DOMElement} node
   * @param {object} styles
   * @param {ReactDOMComponent} component
   */
  setValueForStyles: function (node, styles, component) {
    if (false) {
      ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onHostOperation({
        instanceID: component._debugID,
        type: 'update styles',
        payload: styles
      });
    }

    var style = node.style;
    for (var styleName in styles) {
      if (!styles.hasOwnProperty(styleName)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (false) {
        warnValidStyle(styleName, styles[styleName], component);
      }
      var styleValue = dangerousStyleValue(styleName, styles[styleName], component);
      if (styleName === 'float' || styleName === 'cssFloat') {
        styleName = styleFloatAccessor;
      }
      if (styleValue) {
        style[styleName] = styleValue;
      } else {
        var expansion = hasShorthandPropertyBug && CSSProperty.shorthandPropertyExpansions[styleName];
        if (expansion) {
          // Shorthand property that IE8 won't like unsetting, so unset each
          // component to placate it
          for (var individualStyleName in expansion) {
            style[individualStyleName] = '';
          }
        } else {
          style[styleName] = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }

};
```

Got the error on "style[styleName] = styleValue;"

Answer (score 2):

In React (not the React Native), to merge the styles could use the  javascript function ***Object.assign()***

```
var textStyles = Object.assign({}, 
 styles.tile,
 tile.position,
 styles.emptytile,
 );
 <div key={tile.id} style={textStyles}>
```

Check how you have used the styles.

Comment: I have used style --- 
'const styles = {
  menuItemStyle: {
   fontSize:12,
  },
  listItemStyle: {
   fontSize:12,
  },
};
menuItemStyle={styles.menuItemStyle}'